# Fastest way to format a phone number in C#?

Tags: c#

What is the fastest way to format a string using the US phone format [(XXX) XXX-XXXX] using c#?

My source format is a string.

Comment: whats your source format? another string? plain numbers, not other characters?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:(###) ###-#### x ###}", double.Parse("1234567890123"))
```

Will result in (123) 456-7890 x 123

Comment: I'm curious, why the double.Parse instead of the int.Parse? Surely int is faster.

Comment: How does this performance compare to the substring method.  do you know if the ##-##... is it just parsing with a substring type technique?

Comment: I just tested with int and it threw a "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32." exception.

Comment: maybe long is long enough. i dunno enough of .net to know about their length :) decimal would certainly do it thou, but not sure whether you can still do the ##'s then?

Comment: Ok, good point about int not being large enough, an int64 then?

Comment: Using an integer for an identifier like a phone number is bad practice, using a floating point type is dangerous: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

Comment: Phone numbers could start with 0 and be truncated if stored as anything other than string. Best to remove all non-integer characters (if any) and then format the string phone using substrings of the phone number and any spaces and characters desired. Also a good idea to store the formatted phone number as another property

Comment: Tried this with int and the phone number was too large to be an int. 
That's one reason to use double.

Answer (score 8):

This assumes that you have the phone number with the appropriate number of digits stored like:

```
string p = "8005551234";

string formatedPhoneNumber = string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", p.Substring(0, 3), p.Substring(3, 3), p.Substring(6, 4));
```

Answer (score 5):

This will take a string containing ten digits formatted in any way, for example `"246 1377801"` or even `">> Phone:((246)) 13 - 778 - 01 <<"`, and format it as `"(246) 137-7801"`:

```
string formatted = Regex.Replace(
   phoneNumber,
   @"^\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*$",
   "($1$2$3) $4$5$6-$7$8$9$10");
```

(If the string doesn't contain exactly ten digits, you get the original string unchanged.)

Edit:

A fast ways to build a string is to use a StringBuilder. By setting the capacity to the exact length of the final string you will be working with the same string buffer without any reallocations, and the ToString method will return the buffer itself as the final string.

This assumes that the source string contains only the ten digits:

```
string formatted =
   new StringBuilder(14)
   .Append('(')
   .Append(phoneNumber, 0, 3)
   .Append(") ")
   .Append(phoneNumber, 3, 3)
   .Append('-')
   .Append(phoneNumber, 6, 4)
   .ToString();
```

Comment: Yow... why not just run 1 regex to strip non-digits and a second to do the capturing/replacing?  Wouldn't be as fast but it would be hella cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

I would assume it'd be:

```
var number = string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", oldNumber.Substring(0, 3), oldNumber.Substring(3, 3), oldNumber.Substring(6));
```

This assumes that you have the number stored as "1234567890" and want it to be "(123) 456-7890".

Answer (score 1):

Not the fastest way, but you can use Extension Methods (note that the parameter must be cleaned up of any previous phone format):

```
public static class StringFormatToWhatever
{
    public static string ToPhoneFormat(this string text)
    {        
        string rt = "";
        if (text.Length > 0)
        {            
            rt += '(';
            int n = 1;
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                rt += c;
                if (n == 3) { rt += ") "; }
                else if (n == 6) { rt += "-"; }
                n++;
            }
        }
        return rt;
    }
}
```

Then, use it as

```
myString.ToPhoneFormat();
```

Modify to your needs if you want to:

- Include phone extension (x1234)
- Clean the parameter of any existing phone format inside the method
- Use dash instead of parenthesis
- Eat a sandwich ... you name it! :)

You can also use this to format the string in each user input.

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void txtPhone_Update()       
        {
            string phone = "";
            string phone1 = "";
            int index = 0;
            phone = txtPhone.Text;
            phone1 = "";

            for (index = 0; index < phone.Length; index++)
                if (char.IsDigit(phone[index]))
                { phone1 += phone[index]; }

                {
                    if (phone1[0] == '1') { phone1 = phone1.Remove(0, 1); }

                    {
                            string number = "";
                            number = string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", phone1.Substring(0, 3), phone1.Substring(3, 3), phone1[6..]);
                            phone1 = number;
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea why you wrote `catch { }`. You need to explain your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity This code works to format the phone number to (123) 456-7890.  If you want to display an error message in the catch you can.  Not sure why you would -1 the post. It works without using regex, removes all non-numeric characters. Certainly you could remove the try/catch if it offends you.

Comment: Unless you're catching a **specific** exception that you **meaningfully** handle it is a terrible anti-pattern to just include `try`/`catch`. Further to that you've introduced some sort of UI layer, you have a `if (!condition) {} else { /* do something */ }` when `if (condition) { /* do something */ }` would have been simpler. You also have `phone1 = phone1 + phone[index]` when `phone1 += phone[index]` would have been clearer. Why have anything to do with `DataBindings`? And finally, you allow strings longer than 10 characters and then throw away the extra characters.

Comment: Code edited
This assumes the desired output is 10 digits formatted to (###) ###-####
it will remove a leading 1 and any additional - or . used to enter phone number.