# formatting phone number with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm storing my phone numbers in the database as strings of digits; for instance 4081234567. I'm looking to format this string of digits in the US phone format XXX-XXX-XXXX. This is what I have and it's not working:

```
ThePhone = "4081234567";
char[] ThePhoneString = ThePhone.ToArray();
var ThePhoneFormat = ThePhoneString.Take(3).ToList().ToString() + "-" +ThePhoneString.Skip(3).Take(3).ToString + "-" + ThePhoneString.Skip(6).Take(4).ToString();
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do it; what do you suggest?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need LINQ for this.  This sort of manipulation is not what LINQ is used for.

Use a regular expression or something else instead.

```
var phoneNumber = "4081234567";
var phoneFormat = Regex.Replace(phoneNumber, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "$1-$2-$3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format("{0:(###) ###-#### x ###}", double.Parse("1234567890123"))
```

This question was also asked here
[Fastest way to format a phone number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679740/fastest-way-to-format-a-phone-number-in-c)

Comment: That method does not work because a leading 0 will be dropped in the parse.