# Display Phone Number In Different Country format in asp.net. using locale

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to accept on number from user and display it in diffrent country  format.

like ex: 9080898909 this in inputed number
and displays in loacal country format(any)
908,089,890,9

90.808.989.09

9080,8989,09

90,808,989,09

ther is concept of localization and globlelization, can you tell me how to achive that..?

Answer (score 2):

Store in your resources number formats for different countries and then use it depending on  `CultureInfo.Current`.

How to apply phone number format you can read here: [Fastest way to format a phone number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679740/fastest-way-to-format-a-phone-number-in-c)

```
string currentCulturePhoneFormat = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("phone-format-" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

lblPhone.Text = String.Format(currentCulturePhoneFormat, myEntity.PhoneNumber);
```

in this case you need to store your phne numbers in resources like:

```
phone-format-en-US // for USA
phone-format-de-DE // for Germany
phone-format-fr-FR // for France
```

Or if you are using localizations, just put `phone-number-format` in resource file for each culture.

Comment: @ Samich : Hey Thanx for your valuable Reply, this is great, But can u tell me Should I have to store each country Phone Number Format in each .resx file. is ther other substitution to that..? reply Plz...

Comment: If you have multiple .resx files for each culture - yes, put the phone numbers in each .resx: us phone number in the resource-us.resx, etc.. In code use just `Resources.PhoneNumber` and phone number format will be changed depending on selected culture.

Comment: @Swa,ich,@Swapnil:Can u tell me about how the zip format can define for us and uk,Please tell me..