# How to localize Telephone Number in windows phone?

Tags: c#, localization, windows-phone, string-formatting

Can I format a telephone number as per current culture? For example, to format price as per culture, I use this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object para, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string currency = value.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currency) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currency))
        {
            Int64 C;
            bool result = Int64.TryParse(currency, out C);

            if (result)
            {
                currency = "Price: " + C.ToString("C", culture);
            }
        }

        return currency;
    }
```

This will show my price depending on culture (For es-ES culture -> Price: $5 if value = 5). Is there a way to do something similar for a telephone number?

Comment: I don't think there *is* a single "phonenumber format", even per culture.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to display localized phone numbers, but a very similar question on Stack Overflow provided a solution concept that should work for you. See here:
[Display Phone Number In Different Country format in asp.net. using locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481539/display-phone-number-in-different-country-format-in-asp-net-using-locale)