# Format phone number which starts by 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know none of the phone number starts by 0 in USA. In case if someone enters phone number like this 0237858585 I want to format that as (023) 785-8585.

Currently I'm using `PhoneNumberFormatted = $"{int.Parse(PhoneNumber):(###) ###-####}";` to format phone number which was not working in the above case. It display as (23) 785-8585

Can someone help on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679740/fastest-way-to-format-a-phone-number-in-c

Try this one

Comment: You need to consider this value as a string. Not as a number. As a number leading zero does not have value so when you convert it to number leading zeros will be removed for sure.

Comment: @JonathanSchmold this doesn't help for the number starts by '0'

Comment: Stop trying to store phone numbers (and zip codes, license plates, drivers licenses, barcodes, or anything where performing arithmetic on it doesn't make sense) as integers. There are so many problems with doing that (leading zeroes, nondigits, city codes, extensions, +4 codes) this comment box isn't big enough to mention them all.

Comment: Then don't store your phone number as an integer. As far as I know, the compiler is looking at the integer, and automatically discarding the 0 before you can do anything to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in comment, you need to consider such values as string as converting them to number would loose the leading zeros if it has any.

Assuming that you will have phone number of exact 10 digits you can use following.

```
var phoneNumber = "0237858585";
var formattedNumber = $"({phoneNumber.Substring(0,3)}) {phoneNumber.Substring(3,3)}-{phoneNumber.Substring(6)}";
Console.WriteLine(formattedNumber);
```

You can use this logic conditionally, like if the number start with "0" then use this else you can use the normal formatting which you are using currently.

Comment: you are Mr. Perfect. This handles '0' well in the format.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
String.Format("{0:(0##) ###-####}", 237858585); // Displays (023) 785-8585
```

Answer (score 1):

When formatting numbers, using "#" will drop leading zeros. If you want to keep leading zeros, use "0" as the place holder for leading digits that could be zero.

NOTE: The "0" means display the digit, if there is one, otherwise display "0". It does not mean place a literal "0" at the start of the string.

```
var PhoneNumber = "0237858585";
Console.WriteLine($"{int.Parse(PhoneNumber):(0##) ###-####}");
//Output will be "(023) 785-8585"

PhoneNumber = "237858585";
Console.WriteLine($"{int.Parse(PhoneNumber):(0##) ###-####}");
//Output will be "(023) 785-8585"

PhoneNumber = "1237858585";
Console.WriteLine($"{int.Parse(PhoneNumber):(0##) ###-####}");
//Output will be "(123) 785-8585"

PhoneNumber = "1237858585";
Console.WriteLine($"{int.Parse(PhoneNumber):(000) 000-0000}");
//Output will be "(123) 785-8585"
```

Comment: And how do you know how many leading zeros to pad? If all the OP wanted to do was format _this_ number, why not use a const string?

Comment: @Marc - I just told in case if it start with '0' and not always.

Comment: @user7031310 You can replace all of the "#" with "0". The format string could be "(000) 000-000". The "0" in the format string doesn't mean it's a literal "0". It means that it's a digit with a 0 placeholder if there's no digit.